# Limit WeChat Assets Picker to specific folder(s)?

Tags: flutter, wechat

When I call `AssetPicker.pickAssets` or `AssetPicker.pickAssetsWithDelegate` the UX can load very very slowly (minutes) for a user with a many albums. Is there a way to limit the UX to one, or a subset, of albums (e.g. display only "Recents")?

Background: Some users have hundreds of albums with dates as names, most containing zero photos. I *think* these were auto created by the iPhoto to Photos migration; each iPhoto "event" was converted to an album and named by the date of the event. I'm hoping if I can somehow prevent AssetPicker from searching those albums then the UX will load more quickly. I'm just guessing at solutions. Suggestions appreciated.